# Installing ubuntu 11.04 fails on Dell M6600

Tags: dell

I have a Dell M6600 with Ubuntu 10.04 Howver the X drivers are pretty messed up due to the following issues:
1. After booting the mouse automatically moves to the left top corner of the screen and keeps clicking continuously,
2. the mouse loses focus between windows, making it difficult to switch between the open application windows.

So i thought of upgrading to Ubuntu 11.04 and that failed. Has anyone succesfully installed ubuntu 11.04 or 12.04 beta on a Dell M6600??

Answer (score 0):

-1) Back up your important data and do a fresh install. OR

-2) Reinstall the Synaptics touchpad drivers.

`sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-dev`

and reboot. If still need resolve then:

```
modprobe -r psmouse

modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```